# Identify Mixpanel user actions that occured before login

Tags: mixpanel

I’m having an issue with Mixpanel identification. I want to be able to track events logged before the user logs in and identify them as such.

Here’s an exemple. Louie opens the webpage and visits the “About” page. Using `mixpanel.track('Visit About')`, I’m able to log Louie’s anonymous visit. All is fine and dandy.

Louie decides to log in, and a `mixpanel.identify(user.id)` call identifies him — and subsequent events can be tracked back to Louie. However, the first event (“Visit About”) still shows up with a random, Mixpanel-set distinct ID and hasn’t been associated with Louie.

Is this behaviour expected? What can I do? Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `alias`.

From their [Javascript API reference](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.alias):

> Use alias() when a unique ID is first assigned (registration), and use identify() to identify the user with that unique ID on an ongoing basis (e.g., each time a user logs in after registering). Do not call identify() at the same time as alias().

From your description, it sounds like, rather than viewing the "About" page anonymously and then *logging in*, Louie is viewing the "About" page anonymously and then *signing up*.

In that case, call `alias` when Louie signs up, and call `identify` when he logs in after that. That should associate the random, anonymous Mixpanel ID with Louie's new registered user ID.

Note: using this method will mean that, because Louie triggered an event anonymously and then *logged in*,  Louie's anonymous id for that event will not be linked to his distinct id from logging in. If he had *signed up* after triggering the anonymous event, you would call `alias`, and they would be linked. This is a known limitation of Mixpanel, unfortunately. From their documentation:

> This is the first time he's accessed your site from this device, so we assign a brand new distinct_id to him. He clicks around and then logs in. You should not call mixpanel.alias() in this situation - we haven't seen him on this device, but he is not a new user. ... Instead of calling mixpanel.alias() you should just call mixpanel.identify(). This will remap his phone activity to the original ID he used when signing up for your service, which is the most desirable outcome. This does mean that regrettably the events he fired before logging in will not be associated with him.

More about aliasing in Mixpanel [here](https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/using-mixpanel-alias).

Comment: But what if Louie already has an account? I thougt `mixpanel.alias` should only get called once

Comment: `mixpanel.alias` should only get called once. If Louie already has an account, `mixpanel.identify` should get called when he logs in. If `mixpanel.alias` wasn't called when his account was created, it should never get called. The very last section on this page has a similar instance when you should not call `mixpanel.alias`: https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/using-mixpanel-alias

Comment: As per your original question, if Louie visits the About page, then decides to *log in*, that means he already signed up on a different browser or device. If that's what Louie is doing, see the note I added to my answer.

Comment: Alright, I hope they lift the limitation soon! Thanks Amasa

Answer (score 2):

It took them a while, but here it is...

It's called **Mixpanel Identity merge** and it should fix the whole problem of connecting the actions an anonymous user did before signing up /logging in

> The new system improves the behavior of identify(), alias(), and adds a new event called $merge.
> All pre-authentication activity can now be mapped back to a user
> The ID merge system makes it possible to link pre and post authenticated event streams under a single identifier. This eliminates “false-uniques”, ensuring the most accurate conversion and drop-off rates in funnels and flows.
> Previously, Mixpanel could only map pre-sign up activity back to a user who was later identified. Any activity a user did anonymously before signing in again could not be attributed to that user.

Here is the whole [blog post](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039133851-Moving-to-Identity-Merge)

Answer (score 0):

`Alias` doesn't work for the scenario when existing user logs in, but I found work around for this.

When a user first logs in, check to see if the distinct_id of the request cookie matches the user id.

If they don't match, create a backend task to backfill the anonymous distinct_Id to the user's distinct_id.

Load the events with JQL, then fire them again using the mixpanel import endpoint.

The downside is that you will have duplicate events in the system since there are no way to delete events from the anonymous distinct_id.

For the imported events, you can add a property to them indicating that they are imported so they can be filtered out if need be.